# Triggers on Insert or Update SQL Server (Spatial)

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I am looking at creating a trigger on a live SQL Server spatial table that will update a column when a user either:

1. Creates a new feature
2. Updates the geometry of a feature in a GIS application

Unfortunately I have only been able to work out updating a column when a new feature is created, or updating a column when the geometry column is changed, but not both within one trigger.

Ideal world - attribute `Updated` populates current date for the particular feature that has been created or modified.

This is what I have so far that works only when creating a new feature:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER *[triggername]* ON *[table]* 
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(8)

    SELECT @ID = [ID] FROM *[table]*

    UPDATE *[table]*
    SET Updated = GETDATE()
    WHERE [ID] = @ID
END
GO
```

This works when the geometry is changed

```
CREATE TRIGGER [triggername] ON [table] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE [table] 
    SET [table].Updated = Getdate()
    FROM [table] 
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON [table].id = d.id 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this what you're looking for ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [triggername] ON [table] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS            
BEGIN
    UPDATE [table] 
    SET [table].Updated = Getdate() 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)
END
GO
```